# Changing string date types in series

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, datetime

I have a sample csv dataset with `|` delimiter:

```
row|date|name
1|9-Apr-21|john
2|       |steve
3||
4|10-Dec-21|
```

Note that some fields are null.
I've tried the following code to change those non-empty fields that Date has from `9-Apr-21` to `20210409`.

I've used the following code but it's causing an error. If I have to apply a function, how should I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import datetime
import openpyxl as pxl 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

test=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
my_date = test['date']
dd = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date ,'%d-%m-%y')
return dd
```

Error:

```
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

How would I be able to save the csv file again after changing the date format to YYYYMMDD?

Also, what do I need to do to put dd or my_date back into the original column position in test.csv?

Comment: You have a pandas dataframe, so best use pandas functionality. `pd.to_datetime(test['date'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import datetime
import openpyxl as pxl 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

test=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
my_date = test['date']
dd = my_date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x ,'%d-%b-%y'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it returns an error:

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float.

Comment: it means your data is stored as a float in the `.csv` file, you can change it to string in the apply function. `dd = my_date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x) ,'%d-%b-%y'))`

Comment: Thanks got another error, guess we need to add to ignore nans: ValueError: time data 'nan' does not match format '%d-%b-%y'. I added if pd.notnull(x) else(x) and seems to output value.

Comment: Now the data outputs only in YYYY-MM-DD format. How can I make them into YYYYMMDD format? I tried strftime %Y%m%d but it said it needed a date not a string. So when I changed the lambda to datetime(x), it gave an error saying 'module is not callable'. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can split the dates into list and join them together. Like this; `''.join(date.split('-')`. You can use it in pandas like this; `dd.apply(lambda x: ''.join(str(x).split('-')))`